# Can blocked matrix multiplication operation be optimally reduced to 2*N^3/B^3+N^2/B^2 reads on cache?

Tags: algorithm, caching, optimization

According to this paper https://suif.stanford.edu/papers/lam-asplos91.pdf, the number of data read is 2*N^3+N^2 for a square matrix multiplication operation (X*Y=Z) in the worst case scenario (with e.g. 3 registers). This can be illustrated by the pseudo code below:

```
for i to N:
    for k to N: // X[i][k] is accessed N*N times and is loaded to register 1
        r = X[i][k] 
        for j to N: // Z[i][j] & Y[k][j] are accessed N*N*N times and are loaded to register 2 and 3 respectively
            Z[i][j] += r * Y[k][j]
```

In the paper, it mentioned that if we have a cache size that holds a BxB submatrix of Y plus a B sized cache to hold the results of Z[i][0:B] (for simplicity, let's assume N = 0 (mod B)), the number of data access is reduced to 2*N^3/B+N^2 since each data access to Y and Z is reused B times before the next access:

```
for i to N:
for kk to N with stride of B:
for k to kk:
    r = X[i][k] // still N*N times of access to store value to register 1
    for jj to N with stride of B: // cache loads row Z[i][jj:jj+B] and submatrix Y[kk:kk+B][jj:jj+B]; equivalent to N^3/B times of access for both Z & Y
        Z[i][jj:jj+B] += r * Y[kk:kk+B][jj:jj+B]
```

So, if we have room for 3 BxB submatrices, then the number of data access should optimally be reduced to 2*N^3/B^3+N^2/B^2?

```
for ii to N with stride of B:
for kk to N with stride of B: // cache loads submatrix X[ii:ii+B][kk:kk+B]; equivalent to (N/B)^2 times of access
    r = X[ii:ii+B][kk:kk+B] 
    for jj to N with stride of B: // cache loads submatrices Z[ii:ii+B][jj:jj+B] and Y[kk:kk+B][jj:jj+B]; equivalent to (N/B)^3 times of access for both Z & Y
        Z[ii:ii+B][jj:jj+B] += r * Y[kk:kk+B][jj:jj+B]
```

Surely, this uses more cache space, and yet practically speaking, is this more optimal than the previous solution in terms of power consumption/execution time?